# What are good insulators aside from glass?

Tags: structural-engineering, materials

The insulation properties of glass is apparently a factor in its popularity in modern construction.
Natural stone, by contrast, is a [poor heat insulator](https://carbonlimited.co.uk/2007/03/05/the-myth-of-stone-walls-as-insulation/).
What are some other building materials, i.e. alternatives to glass walls, that may be used in sustainable construction?

Comment: Glass isn't a good thermal insulator.

Comment: Did you mean glass fibre? Many fibrous materials are good insulators as they slow down or stop air movement based heat transfer.

Comment: I think you're mixing up heat and electricity insulators

Comment: Glass is widely used in sustainable building, see https://www.superglass.co.uk/how-were-using-glass-science-to-keep-you-warm/#:~:text=If%20you%20think%20back%20to,other%20hand%2C%20are%20good%20conductors.

Comment: Glass is used to let light in, not to insulate.

Comment: @Cheetaiean, I think you mean "glass is a factor...", not "a factory".

Comment: @Transistor yes indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Glass is not a very good thermal insulator. If you are thinking of/referring to windows, it is important to note that modern windows have "air gaps" between the panes which serve as a thermal break. An easy experiment is if you hold your hand near a single pane window on a cold day, you will be keenly aware of the heat loss.

Some of the best insulators are fiberglass (batts or blown), natural cellulose, or extruded polystyrene boards (XPS, also known as Foam Board).

....

Comment: Is there any other factor then that can explain the popularity of glass in so-called sustainable building?

Comment: @Cheetaiean, it lets in heat via sunlight, minimizing winter heating load in cold climates

Comment: @Cheetaiean, I certainly don't fault you for attributing glass to sustainable buildings. Glass can be a real pane (window pun, sorry). It does not provide a credit to the heat load calculation, and it only hurts the cooling load calculation. It can be used as a structural material, but that can be very expensive and require very precise installation. If you want to know what can make a building more sustainable, I recommend researching LEED certification as they have detailed lists on what can be done. At the end of the day, most people would rather look out a window than stare at a wall.

Answer (score 2):

Glass is not a good insulator. A pane of glass is a bad insulator. You can easily feel how cold a simple pane of glass gets on a winter day such as the windows on a car.

The glass used in in fibrous glass insulation is used, not because glass is a good insulator, but because glass is fireproof. Asbestos used to be used for the same reason. Fiberglass insulation insulates *in spite* of the glass being a poor insulator by being mostly poorly conductive  air and the glass is used to stop that air from being able to circulate.

You could use anything fibrous to do that. It's the air that is actually doing the insulating, not the fibrous material that is used. You could use fibrous copper or aluminum (which are both very good thermal conductors) if you wanted to and it would largely have the same performance. It would just be a LOT more expensive.